# Xcode weird behavior when scrolling text

Tags: xcode

I wonder if there is a way to disable the following:
I have two project windows opened on the screen next to each other and when I position the cursor on the active project window and scroll with the trackpad, I see the other project's content window scrolling too! I need only one to scroll at a time. Is there a way around this annoying feature?

Comment: That doesn't happen to me. Can you give me explicit instructions for reproducing this behavior?

Comment: This seems to be an issue in other applications aswell. I also noticed this issue. You can file a bugreport at bugreport.apple.com